# Is Nihl Xander a requirement to repair the Dreambuilder?

Tags: planescape-torment

I have ... agitated Nihl Xander to a point that he refuses to help repair the Dreambuilder. Apologizing does not help, so I am wondering:

Do I need his help to repair the Dreambuilder or is this quest now failed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely it is now an uncompletable quest. Xander is the one building the thing, after all.

I cannot find any information on how one might aggravate him to begin with, so I'm guessing there was a little accidental stabbing between friends. Regardless, if the current conversation options won't let you proceed, you aren't moving forward.  It's not like he has the machine on him waiting to be looted.

I know theres community mod tweak/fix packs that do alter the Foundry area to react more, including a sort of "your party is hostile" alert level that can cool down over time.  If this is the source, he may chill out if you leave him alone for a while (in-game time). Otherwise you need to find an older save, or live with the quest hanging incomplete.

Comment: Nihl Xander asks for a drop of blood, and my Nameless One was a bit squeamish about the idea of giving up yet another parts of his body. Xander then acts cocky which opens up a few intimidation lines, the final straw was saying "I have killed for less", which only leaves attacking him or fleeing the scene as possible outcomes. Nihl Xander is no one to be intimidated.

Comment: @k0pernikus - Hadn't remembered that option; makes sense though.  It looks like that was the very first ingredient, so I wouldn't have thought it would be a make or break moment.